# Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:8983; Connection refused'

Tags: ubuntu, solr, solarium

No matter what i do i am always getting "Uncaught exception 'Solarium\Exception\HttpException' with message 'Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:8983; Connection refused'" i have installed solarium with composer without any issue but i am still getting above error. curl also seems to be installed don't know what is wrong that make it unable to connect on that port.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if SELinux is preventing apache from talking to port 8983 on the same machine:

```
# getenforce
```

If it says Permissive, SELinux is not the problem. 
If it says Enforcing, try

```
# setenforce 0
```

if you don't get the error anymore, you need to tell SELinux to open port 8983 for httpd.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804062/151163